# '.join' problem (python error) Didn't remove {} or ""

Tags: python

Im trying to make basic inventory system that if you find an item you can view items values. When I run the code everything seems fine but its like the join function didn't work since there is still this {} and this and this ''.I think I may be overcomplicating the code so if you know a way to make it shorter then feel free to comment it.

```
import random

class Player():
  inv = {}
  def __init__(self, hp, dmgl, dmgh):
     self.hp = hp
     self.dmgl = dmgl
     self.dmgh = dmgh

player = Player(100, 20, 30)

def game():
  while True:
    weapon = input("Enter name of weapon that you want: ")
    durability = int(input("Enter durability for " + str(weapon) + ": "))
    player.inv.update({weapon: {"name": weapon, "durability": durability}})
    
    view_inv = input("Do you wish to view your inventory? ")
    if view_inv == 'yes':
      view_item = input("Name of item: ")
      if view_item in player.inv:
        get_item_info = player.inv.get(view_item)
        print(str(view_item) + ":" , ",".join({str(get_item_info) for v in player.inv}))
      

game()
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

is it: 

name: ItemName, durability: 10

or is it:

itemName: 10 ?

Comment: my desired output is for example, sword: name: sword, durability: 100

Comment: "You can ignore most of the code in the classes apart from the inv variable" don't ask us to ignore things, *you* should provide a [mcve]

Comment: You need to re-write the line where you are printing stuff. It's kinda wrong. Debug it line by line, you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your print line with

```py
prop = ", ".join([f"{key}: {val}" for key, val in get_item_info.items()])
print(f"{view_item}: {prop}")
```

`get_item_info.items()` produces a list of tuples of key value pairs for every entry in your dictionary: `[(name, theName), (durability: 10), ...]`

The `f"{key}: {val}" for key, val in ...` creates for each tuple a string.

With `", ".join(..` the list of strings is joined together.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the print statment should read

```
print(str(view_item) + ": " + " ".join([f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in get_item_info.items()]))
```

If this were my code, I would write a generic function that takes a dictionary an returns a oneline string representation of the dictionary, like so:

```
def pprint_dict(dictionary):
    """Return a single line string of all keys and values in the dictionary."""
    out = " ".join([f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in dictionary.items()])
    return out
```

But if it were really my code, `pprint_dictionary` would take an optional `keys` parameter that would allow me to specify which keys in the dictionary I wanted:

```
def pprint_dict(dictionary, keys=None):
    """Return a single line string of all keys and values in keys."""
    if keys is None:
        keys = dictionary.keys()
    out = " ".join([f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in dictionary.items() if k in keys])
    return out
```

Then, in your print statement above, it would read:

```
print(str(view_item) + ": " pprint_dict(get_item_info)
```

Comment: One of the reasons that I would that `pprint_dict` function is that it makes my code easier to debug later. If there's an error, then I can try passing dictionaries to it without running a whole block of code to find out what's wrong. Code is always easier to debug and fix when you can pass artificial objects and data around.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name from `player` to `Player` cause Python is case-sensitive, and you used the wrong name `player` everywhere in the code.

### Fixed Code

```py
class Player():
  inv = {}

def game():
  while True:
    weapon = input("Enter name of weapon that you want: ")
    durability = int(input("Enter durability for " + str(weapon) + ": "))
    Player.inv.update({weapon: {"name": weapon, "durability": durability}})
    
    view_inv = input("Do you wish to view your inventory? ")
    if view_inv == 'yes':
      view_item = input("Name of item: ")
      if view_item in Player.inv:
        get_item_info = Player.inv.get(view_item)
        print(str(view_item) + ":" , ",".join({str(get_item_info) for v in Player.inv}))
      
game()
```

### Output

```
Enter name of weapon that you want: ga
Enter durability for ga: 100
Do you wish to view your inventory? yes
Name of item: ga
ga: {'name': 'ga', 'durability': 100}
Enter name of weapon that you want:
....
```

## But

### The logic is kinda *wrong* and, I felt like making it more *functional*

So added two methods in class `Player` for *adding* and *retrieving* the item from the inventory in a cleaner way.

#### Also!

- I made a list of inputs, so I can test the logic quickly
- Removed Unused import statements

### Here's the final code

```py
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inv = {}

    def add_item(self, inventory_type, name, durability):
      
        inventory_type = inventory_type.title()
        name = name.title()
        
        if any([i for i in self.inv.get(inventory_type, []) if i["name"] == name]):
            print("[Error] Item with same name already exists!")
            return

        if self.inv.get(inventory_type, None) == None:
            self.inv[inventory_type] = [
                {"name": name, "durability": durability}
            ]
            
        else:
            self.inv[inventory_type].append(
                {"name": name, "durability": durability}
            )

        print(f"[Success] Item Named \"{name}\" of type \"{inventory_type}\" inserted in Inventory!")
        
    def get_item(self, view_item):
        view_item = view_item.title()
        for inventory_type in self.inv:
            for item in self.inv[inventory_type]:
                # print(item)
                if item["name"] == view_item:
                    return f"{inventory_type}: {item}"


def game():
      # while True:
      player1 = Player()
      # inventory_type = input("Enter type of the inventory_type: ")
      # name = input("Enter name of the inventory_type: ")
      # durability = int(input(f"Enter durability for {inventory_type} named {name!s}: "))

      items = [
          ("sword", "Nightmaria2", 150),
          ("shield", "defencia", 100),
          ("sword", "Nightmare", 120),
          ("sword", "Nightmare", 30)
      ]

      # Add Items in player1's inventory
      for item in items:
          player1.add_item(*item)
          
      # Display Items using their name
      for item in items:
          if (item_info := player1.get_item(item[1])):
              print(item_info)


game()
```

### Output

```
[Success] Item Named "Nightmaria2" of type "Sword" inserted in Inventory!
[Success] Item Named "Defencia" of type "Shield" inserted in Inventory!
[Success] Item Named "Nightmare" of type "Sword" inserted in Inventory!
[Error] Item with same name already exists!
Sword: {'name': 'Nightmaria2', 'durability': 150}
Shield: {'name': 'Defencia', 'durability': 100}
Sword: {'name': 'Nightmare', 'durability': 120}
Sword: {'name': 'Nightmare', 'durability': 120}
```

I changed the main logic for inserting items to cause a Player can have multiple swords in his/her inventory, so,

I made a list for storing it, also, I handle the duplicates too in case the player tries to add an item of same name of same type.